# Read array data from a CSV or a config file instead of __DATA__ inside Perl script

Tags: perl

I'm a novice in Perl and recently came through a perl script which reads array data from `__DATA__;` (a inline data statement inside the perl script at the bottom) using `@flatfiledata = <DATA>;`

data looks as below inside the script at the bottom:

```
__DATA__;
Arrays
@cab_method::Concentration::Dilution
@cab04_cartypes::XXXX Dye::Gag XXXXXX::LuciXXXX::Firefly LuciXXXX::Renilla LucifXXXX

__END__;
```

I would like to keep this data inside a config file either csv or a tab delimited file
and then read this data into array.

below is the current subroutine which read this data from `__DATA__` statement at the bottom.

```
# read data from __DATA__ section at end of program and put data into @flatfiledata array
@flatfiledata = <DATA>;
&ReadArraysAndHashes;

sub ReadArraysAndHashes {
    foreach $line (@flatfiledata) {
        chomp $line;

        # ok, some weird newline chars have ended up in data section, so...
        $line =~ s/\r|\n//g;

        # skip any lines that do not contain at least one '::'
        # (probably blank lines or comments)

        unless ( $line =~ /::/ ) { next }

        #split all the elements in the line into an array
        my @elements = split( /::/, $line );

        # The first element is the key;
        my $key = shift(@elements);

        # if the key starts with a '@,' you have an array;
        # if it starts with a '%,' it is a hash
        # either way, delete the symbol from the key

        $key =~ s/^(.)//;
        my $array_or_hash = $1;

        # create a hash of hashes
        if ( $array_or_hash eq '@' ) {
            $clrdata{array}{$key} = \@elements;
            @{$key} = @{ $clrdata{array}{$key} };
        }
        elsif ( $array_or_hash eq '%' ) {
            if ( $#elements % 2 != 1 ) {
                print "odd number of elements for $key\n";
            }
            my %hash = @elements;
            $clrdata{hash}{$key} = \%hash;
        }
    }
}


__DATA__;
Arrays
@cab_method::Concentration::Dilution
@cab04_cartypes::XXXX Dye::Gag XXXXXX::LuciXXXX::Firefly LuciXXXX::Renilla LucifXXXX

__END__;
```

Comment: [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) the config file and read it instead of DATA: `open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/config' or die $!; @flatfiledata = <$fh>;`.

Comment: Also, once you've read your data from a file instead of from `__DATA__` and so populated with it the array `@flatfiledata`, **pass that explicitely** to the sub that needs it (`ReadArraysAndHashes`).  Don't rely on the sub picking it up because it's in the scope or some such, like it does now.  Pass the data that the sub needs to the sub.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic answer**

`DATA` is just a filehandle, so it can easily be replaced with any other filehandle.

```
open my $config_fh, '<', 'some_config_file'
  or die "Can't open config file: $!\n";

@flatfiledata = <$config_fh>;
```

**More tips**

One thing that we've learned from many decades of computer programming is that it's a bad idea for a subroutine to access global variables. All data used by a subroutine should either be passed to the subroutine as parameters or created within the subroutine. Your `ReadArraysAndHashes()` subroutine uses the global `@flatfiledata` variable. You should either pass the data into the subroutine:

```
open my $config_fh, '<', 'some_config_file'
  or die "Can't open config file: $!\n";

@flatfiledata = <$config_fh>;

ReadArraysAndHashes(@flatfiledata);

# And in the subroutine
sub ReadArraysAndHashes {
  my @flatfiledata = @_;

  # Rest of the code is the same
  ...
}
```

Or you should read the data inside the subroutine:

```
ReadArraysAndHashes();

# And in the subroutine
sub ReadArraysAndHashes {

  # We don't need the @flatfiledata array
  # as we can read the filehandle directly

  open my $config_fh, '<', 'some_config_file'
  or die "Can't open config file: $!\n";

  foreach $line (<$config_fh>) {
    # Your existing code
    ...
  }
}
```

It also look like your subroutine is writing to a global variable called `%clrdata`. That's also a bad idea. Consider returning that variable from your subroutine instead.

```
%clrdata = ReadArraysAndHashes();

# And in the subroutine
sub ReadArraysAndHashes {
  # All of the code
  ...

  return %clrdata;
}
```

**Extra reading**

Two final tips to consider:

- Take a look at restricting the scope of your variables using [my](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my).
- [Don't use ampersands to call subroutines](https://perlhacks.com/2015/04/subroutines-and-ampersands/).